# Hover over text issue, class properties do not apply to a span in a <p>tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a pure CSS hover effect on a block of text. This is the html..

`<p class="background-switch">Ok, <span style="color:red;">now that</span> you've done that, hover me next!</p>`

and the CSS..

```
.background-switch {
text-align: center;
padding: 1em;
max-width: 250px;
font-size: 2.2em;
border-radius: 30px;
background-color: pink;
}

.background-switch:hover {
background-color: lightblue;
color: white ; 
}
```

It works fine without the `<span>` in the `<p>` tag..but the thing is I need the color of the "now that" to be red before hovering, and white when hovering. This is not the case as the red refuses to turn white when hovering. Is there a way to make the class property applicable to the `<span>` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have:

```
<span style="color:red;">
```

Which is an `inline style`, it's not getting over-ridden.

The best way to fix this is to move that `inline style` to the CSS

```
.background-switch span {color:red;}
.background-switch:hover span {color:#fff;}
```

Or if you want to keep the `inline style`, then add `!important` in your CSS, so that the rule overrides the `inline` rule.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xtF9/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your span

```
<p class="background-switch">Ok, <span class="random-class">now that</span> you've done that, hover me next!</p>
```

Then in your css :

```
.background-switch {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    max-width: 250px;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: pink;
}

.random-class {
     color:red;
}

.background-switch:hover,
.background-switch:hover .random-class {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: white ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.background-switch:hover span {
    color: inherit !important;
}
```

You need !important to overwrite the inline styling on the span tag. Best would be if you replaced the inline styling with a class instead, this would remove the need for !important.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because of the selector precedence in CSS. Inline styles trump everything else. So:

`<span style="color: red;">` ignores other styles.

Adding a class to your span will fix this:

`<span class="something">`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the style="color:red;" from your span, and then add the following to your CSS:

```
.background-switch span {
color:red;
}

.background-switch:hover span {
color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.background-switch span {color: red;}    
.background-switch:hover span {color: #fff;}
```

Remove inline style from span

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like this could help

> .background-switch > span { color:red; }
>
> .background-switch:hover > span { color:white; }

and remove the style inline style="color:red;